# utf-8 encoding and greek characters

Tags: python, utf-8, beautifulsoup

While I managed to get all the data that I need as well as save it on a cv file, the output I get is in UTF-8 format, which is normal(correct me If I'm wrong)

TBH I've already "played" with the .encode() and .decode() option without any results.

here is my code

```
brands=[name.text for name in Unibrands]
```

here is the output

```
u'Spirulina \u0395\u03bb\u03bb\u03b7\u03bd\u03b9\u03ba\u03ae'
```

And this is the desired output

```
u'Spirulina Ελληνική'
```

Comment: print() the result.

Comment: Basically, you’re looking at the `repr()` output of said string, where it’s normal that you get escape sequences for certain characters. If you `print()` the result as @宏杰李 suggested, then you will properly get your string output.

Comment: @宏杰李 I did that and the result is  u'Spirulina \u0395\u03bb\u03bb\u03b7\u03bd\u03b9\u03ba\u03ae'

Comment: The `u'` prefix means that you’re still looking at the `repr()` output of said string instead of the string content. – Are you printing the string or the `brands` list?

Comment: In case it wasn't clear through the tags that I used for the question, I work with beautifoulSoup...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That string is already fine; you're seeing the `repr` of it, which does escape certain characters because this is intended to be safe to copy and paste directly into Python source code (which in Python 2.x means it needs to have only printable ASCII characters) - eg, `\u0395` represents the codepoint [U+0395 GREEK CAPITAL LETTER EPSILON](https://codepoints.net/U+0395). You're seeing this form of it because printing a list (or other container) always shows you the `repr` of its contents - if you instead `print` the string directly, you should see an appropriate glyph instead of the escaped form:

```
>>> print(u'Spirulina \u0395\u03bb\u03bb\u03b7\u03bd\u03b9\u03ba\u03ae')
>>> 'Spirulina Ελληνική'
```

You could also consider upgrading to a newer Python version; Python 3.5 (and possibly earlier 3.x versions) no longer escape these letters in the `repr`, since Python now accepts Unicode characters in source files by default.

Comment: I think that bs4 is not compitable with python 3.5 and later versions

Comment: @volpym according to [its pypi page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4/), bs4 does support 3.x. It doesn't matter that it only says 3.4, later 3.x versions are still compatible.

Comment: Well I upgraded to python 3.0 and started getting the desired output. Thus I marked your answer ;)